# Azure SAS for one container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am able to generate SAS token for the storage account from the Azure portal but the problem which I am facing is explained below-

Storage account consists of two Containers. One container file has to be given access for the users whom I will provide the SAS token and one container should be completely private means user cannot see this container.

Problem is if I am generating SAS token and login into Azure explorer using that SAS token,I am seeing both the containers but my requirement is to see only 1 container. Is there any way to give permission for only one container by generating SAS token using Azure portal without creating any custom application for generating these tokens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way to do that would be to use powershell:

```
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -Name 'name'
$sasToken = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Permission r -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(2.0) -Name 'container name'
```

you could issue this command with `-debug` switch, capture the rest call and use that call to mimic it, using arm client, or custom app or whatever.

Comment: there is no way to do using portal?

Comment: as far as I can tell - no.

Comment: I am connecting to Azure explorer using SAS token generated from the portal. now if I generate this SAS token from PowerShell, will it make any difference while connecting to Azure Explorer?

Comment: well, this token is scoped to one container only

Comment: I think I got the answer but need to verify whether it is working as per my expectation.

Comment: hey, did you verify this? :) everything is fine? @Abhishekkumar

Comment: Container access is working fine but later I got one more requirement to give access only for range of IPs but didn't work only. When I generated SAS token with IP range it was not at all working then later we need to drop this plan. May be I will share my code as well in the comment after sometime

Answer (score 2):

The Azure CLI alternative:

**az storage container generate-sas --account-name ACCOUNT_NAME --account-key ACCOUNT_KEY --https-only --expiry 'YYYY-MM-DD' --name CONTAINER_NAME --permissions r**

Valid permissions: (a)dd (c)reate (d)elete (l)ist (r)ead (w)rite

For more information, check out: **az storage container generate-sas -h**